# Processing CSV files from the Web using embedded Java database

Tags: java, csv, hsqldb, data-processing

Short version: assuming I don't want to keep the data for long, how do I create a database programmaticly in HSQLDB and load some CSV data into it to? My schema will match the files exactly and the files do have adequate column names.

This is an unattended process.

Details:

I need to apply some simple SQL techniques to three CSV files downloaded via the web, then create some DTOs which I can then use with some existing code to process them some more, and save them via REST. I don't really want to mess around with databases but the CSV files are linked by foreign keys, so I was thinking of using an in-memory embedded database to do the work, then throw the whole lot away.

I had in mind a command line app working like this:

1. Create a fresh database in HSQLDB.
2. Start three HTTP GETs in three
   threads using Apache HttpClient.
3. Import the CSVs into three HSQLDB
   MEMORY tables.
4. Run some SQL.
5. Parse the results into my existing
   DTOs.
6. Etc...

I could use pointers to code and utilities helpful for items 1, and 3. Also is there an alternative to HSQLDB I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [opencvs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). It helps you to parse CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

The command line app to use is the SqlTool utility jar that is supplied with HSQLDB. Your procedure can be completed as follows:

1. Create a fresh HSQLDB in-memory database (just connect to the in-memory database).
2. Start three HTTP GETs using Apache HttpClient to get the CSV files.
3. Create three HSQLDB TEXT tables and set the SOURCE of these tables to the CSVs
4. Run some SQL. Parse the results into your existing DTOs.

Creating TEXT tables in pure in-memory tables was not possible when the question was asked. It is now fully supported in HSQLDB 2.x versions.

Comment: This is an old question and the solution has now been coded and forgotten. I do recall the outline of what I did though and very little is covered here. Yours might be the better answer if you expanded on point 3. Both answers could use some detail around bootstrapping the right helpers etc to get a throw-away Hibernate session (or similar).

Comment: Point 3 is covered in detail in the HSQLDB guide.